# Create a plist file in iOS error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, plist

I want to write the method which should create for writing a plist file. I got the example code in the Web but can not understand what is wrong with it.  First of all, when I try to call this method - I get a message in log:

```
2013-03-28 15:33:47.953 ECom[6680:c07] Property list invalid for format: 100 (property lists cannot contain NULL)
2013-03-28 15:33:47.954 ECom[6680:c07] An error has occures <ECOMDataController: 0x714e0d0>
```

Than why does this line return (null)?

```
 data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:plistData format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:nil error:&err];
```

and the last question - how to remove the warning message for the same line?

```
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type 'NSPropertyListWriteOptions' (aka 'insigned int')
```

h-file

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ECOMDataController : NSObject
{
    CFStringRef trees[3];
    CFArrayRef treeArray;
    CFDataRef xmlValues;
    BOOL fileStatus;
    CFURLRef fileURL;
    SInt32 errNbr;
    CFPropertyListRef plist;
    CFStringRef errStr;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary * rootElement;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary * continentElement;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * country;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray * elementList;
@property(nonatomic, strong)  id plistData;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * plistPath;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSData * data;
@property(nonatomic, strong) id filePathObj;



-(void)CreateAppPlist;

@end
```

m-file

```
    #import "ECOMDataController.h"

@implementation ECOMDataController

@synthesize rootElement, continentElement, country, name, elementList, plistData, data, plistPath;

- (void)CreateAppPlist {

    // Get path of data.plist file to be created

    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Create the data structure

    rootElement = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
    NSError *err;
    name = @"North America";
    country = @"United States";

    continentElement = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:name, country, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name", @"Country", nil]];

    [rootElement setObject:continentElement forKey:@""];

    //Create plist file and serialize XML

    data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:plistData format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:nil error:&err];
    if(data)
    {
        [data writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error has occures %@", err);
    }

    NSLog(@"%@   %@    %@", plistPath, rootElement, data);

}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are serializing the wrong element, replace `plistData` by `rootElement` (and `nil` by `0`) in

```
data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:plistData format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:nil error:&err];
```

Comment: Hi, Martin, I've replaced the line - and now from all the problems I got only one - the warning message on options:nil. Any idea? Thank u in advance, unfortunately I had ne reputation to thank u(

Comment: @ShurupuS:  Replace `nil` by `0` (write options is an integer, not a pointer).